# Select randomly And Sort the records

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

I have a table which has ID,name and Level columns.I want to SELECT the records of the Table by this pattern : 
First Select Them randomly and then sort those random records by level column.

for example : my sample table and records:

```
ID      name         Level
--------------------------------- 
1      red-book         1
2      blue-pen         10
3      black-board      12
4      balck-Book       1
5      white-book       1
6      red-pen          10
7      green-pen        10
```

And the result should be something like this :

```
ID            name             level
------------------------------------------
3             black-board      12
6             red-pen          10
2             blue-pen         10
7             green-pen        10
4             balck-Book       1
1             red-book         1
5             white-book       1
```

I've  also used

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY NEWID(),Level DESC
```

And

```
 SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDERBY NEWID())As TempTbl 
 ORDER BY Level DESC
```

And

```
 CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable (ID INT,name Nvarchar(256),Levels INT)

 INSERT INTO #MyTempTable SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY NEWID()

 SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable ORDER BY Levels DESC
```

Comment: So what is your question and what have you tried?

Comment: And which database are you using?

Comment: And what good would it do to select all the records *randomly* and then sort on level in descending order? Sounds like a simple `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY level DESC;` is enough, I don't understand the "randomly" part.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY NEWID(),Levels DESC and i didn't see my desired asnwer!

Comment: my db engine is MSSQL.

Comment: and another code that i've used is SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM Mytable ORDER BY NEWID())AS TempTbl ORDER BY Levels DESC.....and many errors!

Comment: Why do you order by newid?? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Maybe you want to randomly select a fixed number of records and then sort this small amount of records.

Comment: ===> Florin Ghita  ====  No.the maximum number of records should be infinite

Comment: ===> Roy Dictus ==== order by NEWID() selects randomly from a table.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY Level DESC, NEWID()` should work.

Comment: well i have to say that i'm new to mssql

Comment: ===> martin smith === worked like a charm! i've used this query before and it didn't give me my desired result. but now it surprisingly gave me the correct answer.thanks dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,name,level
FROM sample
ORDER BY level DESC,NEWID()
```

Comment: just like " SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY NEWID(),Levels DESC " gives me the same result! it sorts the ID column either.

Comment: `RAND()` is only evaluated once per statement not per row in SQL Server so this won't work.

Comment: My query orders by level descending. Per level the data gets ordered randomly. If this is not what you want, the question is unclear.

Comment: @Martin Smith In comments above is stated mssql is used. I know the issue with sql server but with mssql this is not a problem

Comment: mssql **is** sql server.